# Native Images generated against multiple versions of assembly System.Net.Http.Phone

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, windows-phone-8.1

I have created a windows phone App 8.1 with xamarin shared project. After creating the XAP file, I tried to install in the WP device using Windows Phone 8.1 Deployment tool. It is being installed without any problem.

But if I install the same using different machine and device it shows the following error.

Native Images generated against multiple versions of assembly System.Net.Http.Phone

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24740534/error-native-images-generated-against-multiple-versions-of-assembly-system-net) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24305952/native-images-generated-against-multiple-versions-of-assembly-system-net-http), but could not make out since the difference in assembly.

Should I need to do something in the other machine or need to do something in my development machine to get this thing done. Please Help :(